# call function in a C program

Tags: c

I am working on a C program.
The description of it is: There are 3 types of transport:

- Taxi
- bus
- train.

Every single one has a different price for day and night ride. I am able to do the program but I want to change it a little bit by making them as functions. That is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float getTaxi(int type, int time)
{
    int distance;

    float tstarter = 0.7;
    float tday = 0.79;
    float tnight = 0.9;

    if(type == 1)
    {
        if(time == 1)
        {
            float price = tstarter + distance * tday;
            printf("%.2f", price);
        }
        else if(time == 2)
        {
            float price = tstarter + distance * tnight;
            printf("%.2f", price);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{

    int type;
    int distance;
    int time;

    float tstarter = 0.7;
    float tday = 0.79;
    float tnight = 0.9;

    float bus = 0.09;
    float train = 0.06;

    printf("Vehicle types:\nTaxi = 1\nBus = 2\nTrain = 3\n \nTime: \nDay = 1\nNight = 2\n");

    printf("\nWhat vehicle do you want to use: ");
    scanf("%d", &type);

    printf("What time is it: ");
    scanf("%d", &time);

    printf("How long do you want to travel: ");
    scanf("%d", &distance);

    if(type == 1)
    {
        if(time == 1)
        {
            getTaxi(1, 1);
        }
        else if(time == 2)
        {
            getTaxi(1, 2);
        }
    }

    if(type == 2)
    {
        if(time == 1)
        {
            if(distance >= 20)
            {
                float price = distance * bus;
                printf("%.2f", price);
            }
            else{
                printf("Better get Taxi!");
            }
        }
        else if(time == 2)
        {
            if(distance >= 20)
            {
                float price = distance * bus;
                printf("%.2f", price);
            }
            else{
                printf("Better get Taxi!");
            }
        }
    }

    else if(type == 3)
    {
        if(time == 1)
        {
            if(distance >= 100)
            {
                float price = distance * train;
                printf("%.2f", price);
            }
            else{
                printf("Better get Taxi or Bus!");
            }
        }
        else if(time == 2)
        {
            if(distance >= 100)
            {
                float price = distance * train;
                printf("%.2f", price);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should also pass `distance` variable as argument. It is never initialized in your GetTaxi function.
Also consider changing function signature to `void GetTaxi(..)`, because you are not returning any value anyway.

Comment: @Blomex It used to give me random numbers and passing `distance` variable as argument fixed it. Anyway I am not sure how to ask the user to enter `distance` value now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I already mentioned you should pass `distance` variable as argument. You should also remove `int distance` inside your `getTaxi()` function, because it will be passed as argument instead.

Also function can be `void` because you are not returning any value.

```
void getTaxi(int type, int time, int distance){
printf("Distance is %d\n", distance);
(...)
}
```

you can ask the user to enter `distance` same way you used to and pass the variable as argument to function:

`scanf("%d", &distance);`

`getTaxi(1, 1, distance);`

You also dont need all those `if's`
you can just call `getTaxi(type, time, distance);`